# Flask back-end returning invalid data

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm building a Flask backend. I have this route that should return the ID that matches the email

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    email = request.json['data']
    id = session.query(Users).filter_by(email=Users.estudent_email)
    result = users_schema.dump(id)
    return jsonify(result)
```

I'm currently sending it this data

```
{
    "data": "name.lastname@email.com"
}
```

But it returns a whole bunch of data which is incorrect. It should return a single ID from the database that is assigned to the user that holds the email. What might be the cause? I'm using Marshmallow and SQLAlchemy ORM.

Comment: If you don't want the full record, don't do `users_schema.dump`.

Comment: Variable ``email`` arrives corretly to the server? What's the output of ``result``? Can you check those?

Comment: @CherryDT What should I use instead then?

Comment: @TomásDenisReyesSánchez Yeah I'm using postman, output of `result` is a bunch of data not connected to the sent POST request. It includes `ID` `First name` and the rest of data. I'd like to get only ID.

Comment: Then, if it's a dict (use ``type`` built-in function to figure the type) use ``result['ID']`` or if it has an schema, try ``result.get('ID')`` or something like this. Let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in this line:

```
id = session.query(Users).filter_by(email=Users.estudent_email)
```

You seem to have the equality check the wrong way around. `Users.estudent_email` references the entire field of the database, and `email` is a named argument in `filter_by`, *not* `email` that you defined in the previous line.

I can't test but I'm thinking you want:

```
id = session.query(Users).filter(Users.estudent_email==email)
```

*or*

```
id = session.query(Users).filter_by(email=email)
```

As for the serialization, and `result = users_schema.dump(id)`, I have no idea because there is not enough context given to be sure how to make that work.

Comment: The data fetching worked. Now I just have to get that single `id` column from a row. I'm not 100% sure what to use, SQLAlchemy or Marshmallow.

Comment: @floatba then I've misunderstood your question. Does my answer solve any problem? If not, I'll delete. However, I'm a bit confused about what you're asking now

Comment: Partially, it fetches the correct row (the row where `email` is equal to the data sent via POST request) but have to take a single column from it(`id`). I'm missing the part where I fetch the `id` from the row

Comment: Marking your reply as answer. Modifying it to `id = session.query(Users.id).filter(Users.estudent_email==email)` gave me the 'id' only

Comment: @FloatBA because you explicitly queried for id with `query(Users.id)`. If you want the whole record back, just use `query(Users)`

Comment: I realized that. I needed the ID only.